# search box above every column of list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, web-part, sharepoint-server

The problem I am having is that I want to show search box above every column in list in my sharepoint site. But the number of columns in each list are different. Is there a dynamic way to do so??

I am sharing an image below to tell you what I want

[image]

Comment: What technologies can you use? This is not something you can do OOTB I'm afraid

Comment: I am open to any technology which can solve my problem

Comment: I guess text filter search gives me search from all of the columns . I need a way to search only that specific column above which the search box is changed

Comment: Can Any web part can solve this problem??

Comment: I don't see a problem, I see a function that will require custom development ;) Is the view paged, or can it be?

Comment: lets say the number of rows are static then how can I implement search box above every column. I am ready to hard code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution on this link .

Hope this helps

http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com/

***The JQuery script***

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>


google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { 

$(document).ready(function()
{   
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
      containsIgnoreCase: "(a.textContent||a.innerText||jQuery(a).text()||'').toLowerCase().indexOf((m[3]||'').toLowerCase())>=0"
    });


    $("table.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr").each(function()
    {
        if($("td.ms-vh-group", this).size() > 0)
        {
            return; 
        }

        var tdset = "";

        var colIndex = 0;

        $(this).children("th,td").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("ms-vh-icon"))
            {
                // attachment
                tdset += "<td></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                // filterable
                tdset += "<td><input type='text' class='vossers-filterfield' filtercolindex='" + colIndex + "' /></td>";                
            }

            colIndex++;
        });

        var tr = "<tr class='vossers-filterrow'>" + tdset + "</tr>";

        $(tr).insertAfter(this);
    }); 


    $("input.vossers-filterfield")
        .css("border", "1px solid #7f9db9")
        .css("width", "100%")
        .css("margin", "2px")
        .css("padding", "2px")
        .keyup(function()
        {           
            var inputClosure = this;

            if(window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle)
            {
                clearTimeout(window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle);
            }

            window.VossersFilterTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function()
            {
                var filterValues = new Array();

                $("input.vossers-filterfield", $(inputClosure).parents("tr:first")).each(function()
                {               
                    if($(this).val() != "")             
                    {
                        filterValues[$(this).attr("filtercolindex")] = $(this).val();
                    }
                });     


                $(inputClosure).parents("tr.vossers-filterrow").nextAll("tr").each(function()
                {
                    var mismatch = false;

                    $(this).children("td").each(function(colIndex)
                    {
                        if(mismatch) return;

                        if(filterValues[colIndex])
                        {
                            var val = filterValues[colIndex];

                            // replace double quote character with 2 instances of itself
                            val = val.replace(/"/g, String.fromCharCode(34) + String.fromCharCode(34));                         

                            if($(this).is(":not(:containsIgnoreCase('" + val + "'))"))
                            {
                                mismatch = true;
                            }                       
                        }
                    });

                    if(mismatch)
                    {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).show();
                    }       
                });             

            }, 250);
        });
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: All the necessary Information , source code & updates are given in the link . please go through it.

Comment: Please do not only provide links as answer, extend your answer with the important bits from your links. If the links break, your answer will not be very helpful as it looks now.

Comment: got it will update. Thanks for making the site better

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan : i hope now my answer is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in javascript/jQuery before, the only problem is that in order for it to be real-time it needs to load all items in the list (no paging) before you start which allows for a maximum of 5000 items in the list (and loads slowly)

If you don't need real-time, you could set it up to let them type, then hit search and use spservices(jquery addon) to query the list for results in that column.

For the first one, you just load everything using the page view, and assign text boxes based on column detection (I used the css class to select) then as they type you just filter values found in that column by hiding non-conforming rows.

Comment: Where can I find this jQuery or javascript . Can you please share. It would be great help

Comment: lets say the number of rows are static then how can I implement search box above every column. I am ready to hard code it.

Comment: See: http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-jquery-sharepoint-instant-searchfilter/